# ES6 export equivalent for conditional static require exports?

Tags: javascript

I have seen in many projects (like React), they use `require()` to conditionally re-export properties like so:

```js
// index.js

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' {
  exports = require('./cjs/react.production.min.js')
} else {
  exports = require('./cjs/react.development.js')
}
```

I am trying to convert this to its equivalent valid ES6 syntax, preserving individual exported members (for tree shaking).

I have tried this and it works, but you cannot import individual members:

```js
import * as prod from './cjs/react.production.min.js'
import * as dev from './cjs/react.development.js'

let exports = {}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  exports = prod
} else {
  exports = dev
}

export default exports
```

Is there an equivalent for the original using valid ES6 syntax?

I suppose with a smart enough compiler, the assigned keys within the nested modules could be propagated to the top level at build time like this:

```js
import { value_1 as prod_value_1 } from './cjs/react.production.min.js'
import { value_1 as dev_value_1 } from './cjs/react.development.js'

let value_1 = undefined

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  value_1 = prod_value_1
} else {
  value_1 = dev_value_1
}

export { value_1 /* value_2, etc */ }
```

UPDATE:
A little less janky but still requires knowing the exported key names:

```js
import * as prod from './cjs/react.production.min.js'
import * as dev from './cjs/react.development.js'

let selected = undefined

if (true) {
  selected = prod
} else {
  selected = dev
}

export const { value_1, value_2, etc } = selected
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Converting the conditional `require()` statements in CommonJS to ES6 syntax while preserving tree shaking capabilities can be a bit challenging. The approach you've described is on the right track. However, it's important to understand that ES6 `import` and `export` statements are static and can't be used inside conditional blocks like `if` statements.

The approach you've described in the latter part of your question, where you import individual members and then conditionally assign them, is one way to handle this. Here's an expanded and slightly refined version of your approach:

```
import * as prod from './cjs/react.production.min.js';
import * as dev from './cjs/react.development.js';

let finalExports = {};

const keys = Object.keys(prod);
keys.forEach(key => {
  finalExports[key] = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? prod[key] : dev[key];
});

// Explicitly export each member
export const {
  Component1,
  Component2,
  // ... other exports
} = finalExports;
```

This approach does have some downsides:

1. Explicit Listing of Exports: You need to manually list all the
   exports. This can be cumbersome and error-prone, especially if the
   number of exports is large or changes frequently.
2. Build-Time Optimization: While this approach may work at runtime, it
   might not be as efficient for build-time optimizations like tree
   shaking. Since the actual export used is determined at runtime,
   static analysis tools might not be able to determine which exports
   are actually used in the consuming code.
3. Bundle Size: Both prod and dev versions are imported and included in
   the bundle, which could lead to a larger bundle size.

An alternative approach is to use a build tool like Webpack or Rollup to handle environment-specific bundling. These tools can replace imports based on the environment during the build process, which allows for more efficient tree shaking and smaller bundle sizes. Here's an example using Webpack's `DefinePlugin`:

```
// webpack.config.js

const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  // ... other webpack config
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'react': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' 
               ? './cjs/react.production.min.js' 
               : './cjs/react.development.js'
    }
  }
};
```

In your source code, you would then just import from 'react', and Webpack will handle replacing it with the correct file based on the environment. This approach is more maintainable and better for optimization.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the super in depth answer. Nice use of the `export const`. Seems like you must always know the names of the exported keys from the interior dependencies meaning there is no direct translation for the `require` syntax

Comment: You're very welcome! Yes, knowing the names of exported keys is necessary in ES6, unlike CommonJS's `require`, which allows more flexibility but lacks direct translation for this syntax.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy